# Mature content warning at first conversation

Tags: actions-on-google

I don't know how to let the mature content warning only be said at the user's first conversation. There are no events in dialogflow that I can use.

Comment: Welcome :) required detail explanation of your problem also add related tags to kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask & update your question

Answer (score 1):

You would have to check using the webhook, which has a way of knowing when the user has returned to the app or is a new user.

```
app.intent('Incoming mature content', conv => {
  if (conv.user.last.seen) {
    conv.ask('Welcome back!')
  } else {
    conv.ask('Before we continue, you are a new user.')
  }
})
```